# How to override a .less file from custom theme?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, theme

I am using [Argento theme](https://argentotheme.com/) for Magento 2 store. Now I would like to change the font to different Google font.

I saw a file located in vendor/swissup/theme-frontend-argento-home/web/css/source/argento_theme/base/_fonts.less, which has the theme fonts.

What it will take to replace this file with my custom font setup?

Just adding a new font to any element will work, but I would like to keep the theme more lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create custom theme and extend Argento Theme
   app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>
2. edit _typography.less or _fonts.less in your theme with any text editor
3. copy the edited file to app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/
4. Add font files to your local theme directory. For example, app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/fonts

Comment: Did this already not working

Comment: It should be working that way, maybe cached or something?

Comment: I can see the other changes to styles,  only this is not in effect

Comment: It works! I was confused as the fallback font also looks almost similar. Thank you for the efforts

Comment: You're welcome ^^ don't forget to mark this answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way i can think of right now would be creating a custom theme that extends Argento theme and creating a custom _font.less there.

Comment: Using a child theme already, and tried this way but not working

Comment: then you're doing something wrong and we need more information.

Comment: It works! I was confused as the fallback font also looks almost similar. Thank you for the efforts